# How do I connect to a Windows Universal App StreamSocket from a Console Application?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, win-universal-app

I am listening for connections through a Windows Universal App and would like to connect to that App through a Windows Console Application. I have done some basic code which I think should connect but I get a timeout error from the console application.

```
{"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 192.168.0.5:1771"}
```

The windows universal app never even goes into the connection received function.

The Server (UWP):

```
    public async void SetupServer()
    {
        try
        {
            //Create a StreamSocketListener to start listening for TCP connections.
            Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListener socketListener = new Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocketListener();

            //Hook up an event handler to call when connections are received.
            socketListener.ConnectionReceived += SocketListener_ConnectionReceived;

            //Get Our IP Address that we will host on.
            IReadOnlyList<HostName> hosts = NetworkInformation.GetHostNames();
            HostName myName = hosts[3];

            //Assign our IP Address
            ipTextBlock.Text = myName.DisplayName+":1771";
            ipTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Color.FromArgb(255,0,255,0));

            //Start listening for incoming TCP connections on the specified port. You can specify any port that' s not currently in use.
            await socketListener.BindEndpointAsync(myName, "1771");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //Handle exception.
        }
    }
```

The Client (Console Application):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[1024];
            int sent;
            string ip = "192.168.0.5";
            int port = 1771;
            IPEndPoint ipep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port);
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect(ipep); //**************Stalls HERE************
            using (NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ns))
                {
                    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ns))
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine("Hello!");
                        sw.Flush();
                        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        Console.WriteLine("Response: " + sr.ReadLine());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested your code on my side and it can work well. So there is nothing wrong with your code. But I can reproduce your issue by running the server and client on the same device, the client will throw the same exception as you showed above. So please ensure you're connecting from another machine. We cannot connect to a uwp app [StreamSocketListener](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.sockets.streamsocketlistener.aspx) from another app or process running on the same machine,this is not allowed. Not even with a [loopback](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh780593.aspx) exemption.

Please also ensure the `Internet(Client&Server)` [capability](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) is enabled. And on the client you can ping the server `192.168.0.5` successfully.

Comment: Thanks I didn't realize I couldn't run them on the same machine. Why is that? Will it be fixed?

Comment: @SethKitchen, this is not a bug, this is by design. This is restricted by network isolation. May be for security reason.

Comment: I read this "Note As part of network isolation, the system forbids establishing socket connections (Sockets or WinSock) between two UWP apps running on the same machine via either the local loopback address (127.0.0.0) or explicitly specifying the local IP address" at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets - but why can't I connect from a non-UWP app like a local browser? Don't get what the security issue really is, especially when they don't allow using IP address and opening some firewall port at least