# Two way communication between UWP application and Console application

Tags: .net, uwp, .net-core

I want my UWP application to launch and pass a string to a Console application and receive a string result from the console app. Any code help please??

Comment: If it was not UWP it could be reading output from process, MemoryMappedFile. But with uwp I don't know any other approaches rather then TCP connection https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40474244/how-do-i-connect-to-a-windows-universal-app-streamsocket-from-a-console-applicat

Comment: But UWP cannot start executables, because of sandbox limitations. It can only start apps which has specifically registered url in OS.

Comment: You can create UWP console app and install it. https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2018/06/06/c-console-uwp-applications/ Then you may call it by url and get results. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-launch-an-app-for-results

Answer (score 2):

Make your console EXE part of the UWP app package. Then you can launch it via [FullTrustProcessLauncher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.FullTrustProcessLauncher) API and communicate with it via [AppServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service).

If it needs to be external to your package you can still use the same concept, just include a small launcher EXE in your UWP package that will then launch the actual external console EXE.

I have a tutorial posted here with samples that explains all the steps:
https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/

Comment: Stefan, thanks for your answer and tutorial! Still could you please share some code for getting message from console application to UWP? I think your tutorial explains only communication with WinForms/WPF

Comment: It works the same way for console as it does for WPF or Winforms: open an AppServiceConnection to the UWP and use that to send your message (as explained in part 3 of the tutorial). If you need a concrete example with a console app you can find one here: https://stefanwick.com/2018/05/15/global-hotkey-registration-in-uwp/